# How will me leaving my program effect my lab's funding?

Tags: united-states, etiquette, funding, quitting

I'm currently dealing with some personal issues that are affecting my progress in my Ph.D. program. As a result, I intend to leave my program as soon as possible (end of this semester).

However, I want to do the right thing. We recently applied for a grant we are likely to get. I wasn't a student here when the previous grant was given, but I have been included on this grant just submitted. Could my leaving the program affect the chances of getting the grant?
If the grant is awarded, I stay some time to finish my project parts and then leave. Could my PI be penalized for losing a student? Does this affect his reputation?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What country? Usually students are "on" grants, but your pay may have been a line item, is that what you meant?

Comment: USA. I'm not well versed in how grants are written, but yes if in the grant he named his students and their pay...then loses that student. Does that have a large impact on his current funds? Or something they can explain later (in the end grant report)?

Comment: I'm not 100% because I'm not faculty, but individual students are not named. You leaving won't affect anything, they can fund someone else. Or worse case, they send the money back at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows for sure can answer you.

Comment: Even if you were included by name, it should still be fine. The only person the grant depends on that much is the PI, and even then there are means to sort it out given unforeseen circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

> However, I want to do the right thing

The right thing is not to worry about anything as long as you are not breaking obligations or promises.

This is not your problem. The PI is an adult who (supposedly) was trained to manage lab. As any other team, labs need to be able to handle team members leaving due to various circumstances.

> but I have been included on this grant

You are PhD student, which means you were included probably in form of "if grant funded, we'll pay one grad student". Realistically, whether you quit or not will not affect grant application.